# Settings required to set to emulate the FFMPEG '-sameq' flag when using libavcodec

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, libavcodec

Currently attempting to use libavcodec to transcode MP4 (MPEG4 and H264) and MPG (MPEG2) video files into .MP4, .MPG and .AVI files.
Have done this previously using FFMpeg.exe with use of the '-sameq' flag to retain the same/similar quality output file to that of the input file.

Now using av_open_input_file, av_read_frame and avcodec_decode_video2 to open, read and decode the input file, then assigning a AVCodecContext and encoding the data using avcodec_encode_video.  However the output file video quality is pretty poor.

These are the AVCodecContext settings I'm using?:-

```
codecContextOutput->width = SAME AS INPUT FILE;
codecContextOutput->height = SAME AS INPUT FILE;
codecContextOutput->pix_fmt = SAME AS INPUT FILE;
/* frames per second */
AVRational ar; 
ar.num = 1;
ar.den = 25;
codecContextOutput->time_base = ar;
codecContextOutput->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
codecContextOutput->max_b_frames=1;
codecContextOutput->bit_rate = 480000;
```

Does anybody know the additional settings needed to emulate the '-sameq' setting or what additional settings are needed in the AVCodecContext to improve the output quality?

Answer (score 0):

Following further testing and use of some different calls in the Libavformat library, I've found that as long as I set the bit_rate of the output context to the same as the input context then the same quality can be maintained.
This isn't so handy when transcoding from a high bandwidth format like MPEG2, down to an H264 stream since the output bandwidth is probably much greater than it needs to be but it's a solution so that I don't lose quality from the transcoded file.